# Django - reverse not found for included URL pattern

Tags: django

I've got the following in an old Django 1.8 (sorry...) site:

```
url(r"^racing/(?P<type>(dog|horse|pigeon))/", include("racing.urls")),
```

which pulls in the racing URLs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("racing.views",
    url(r"^(?P<season>\d+)/$", "season_view", name="season_home"),
}
```

The view function defines a default for the type argument:

```
def season_view(request, season, type="horse")
```

Which, to my mind, means I should be able to (in a template) do:

```
{% url "season_home" season=nav.season.year %}
```

But it's throwing an error:

```
Reverse for 'season_home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'season': 2019L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'racing/(?P<type>[-\\w]+)/(?P<season>\\d+)/$']
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are using default parameters in your views. So, you are expecting that if you are not passing a `type` parameter through your template, the `type` is set to `horse` as default.

Everything is okay but in your main url patterns, you need to be able to match the rules where no parameter is passed. You can try something like:

```
url(r"^/", include("racing.urls")),
url(r"^racing/(?P<type>(dog|horse|pigeon))/", include("racing.urls")),
```

This configuration helps you to capture both the cases when you supply a `type` parameter or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your url pattern need 2 variables to be passed: `type` and `season`:
So you are passing only `season` and nothing for `type`.

Try to add type like:

```
{% url "season_home" type=my_type season=nav.season.year %}
```

where `my_type` is your type variable.

Comment: There is no need to pass a type parameter as type is used as default parameter in the views.